# Radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{n! x^{2n}}{n^n (1 + x^{2n})}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the radius of convergence of
$$\sum_{n=1} \frac{n! x^{2n}}{n^n (1 + x^{2n})}$$

,which does not seem to be power series?

Ratio test gives me

$$x^2 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n(1+x^{2n})}{(n+1)^n (1+x^{2(n+1)})}$$

Root test gives me

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}}$$

But both looks intimidating and I am having trouble evaluating the limits.

Comment: @Arthur I did but I wasn't expecting to use that. This is a GRE practice problem and I thought Sterling's approximation is somewhat advanced?

Comment: In the ratio test, you are missing an $n^n$ up there next to $1+x^{2n}$

Comment: @HeatTheIce You are right. Edited.

Comment: I am curious: how do they define the radius of convergence of $\sum u_n(x)$ when $u_n(x)$ is not some multiple of $x^n$ but apparently any function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio looks as follows:
$$x^2 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n(1+x^{2n})}{(n+1)^n (1+x^{2(n+1)})}=x^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1+x^{2n}}{1+x^{2(n+1})}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}}=x^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1+x^{2n}}{1+x^{2(n+1})}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}}=x^2\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{e}=\frac{1}{e},{for}\ \mid x\mid>1$$

$$...=x^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1+x^{2n}}{1+x^{2(n+1})}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}}=x^2\frac{1}{e}, for \ 0\le\mid x\mid\le1 $$